# CustomControl Property unable to set via dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have created custom control which contains combo box to display colors and one dependency property `SelectedIndex`. I have used this control in `mainwimdow.xaml` page and tried to set selected index value via dependency property declared in  `mainwimdow.xaml.cs` page.

But when I set any value via dependency property it doesn't work and if I set custom controls property directly in `mainwimdow.xaml` page it works fine. So this means custom control is working fine only value is not setting via dependency property.

Here is the code.

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ConditionsSelectedIndexProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
           "ConditionsSelectedIndex", 
           typeof(int), 
           typeof(MainWindow), 
           new UIPropertyMetadata(3));

    public int ConditionsSelectedIndex
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ConditionsSelectedIndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ConditionsSelectedIndexProperty, value); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetCurrentValue(ConditionsSelectedIndexProperty, 5);
    }
}
```

`MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<controls:ColorComboBoxControl x:Name="cmbConditions" 
          SelectedIndex="{Binding ConditionsSelectedIndex}" 
          Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
```

Following code works fine if I assign hardcoded value like

```
<controls:ColorComboBoxControl x:Name="cmbConditions" 
         SelectedIndex="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
```

If I tried this to check dependency property is working or not then it's work

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ConditionsSelectedIndex}"
           Grid.Column="1" Height="25" Margin="42,143,77,143" >
</TextBlock>
```

So both custom control and dependency property are working fine if tested independently. But its not working when tried to set custom control property via another dependency property.

Comment: have you set DataContext correctly?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `SetCurrentValue(ConditionsSelectedIndexProperty, 5)` and not just `ConditionsSelectedIndex = 5` in the constructor?

Comment: Yes i have set DataContext correctly as :- DataContext = this and tested ConditionsSelectedIndex value by assigning it to Textblock as shown in above post

Comment: Yes i have tried both SetCurrentValue(ConditionsSelectedIndexProperty, 5) and ConditionsSelectedIndex = 5 but doesn't work. As per above posts Value is assigning properly to ConditionsSelectedIndex property but some how unable to reflect when trying to assign to custom control.

Comment: why you are making ConditionsSelectedIndex as dependency property in MainWindow?